# Absolute difference between largest IEEE754 number and its predecesor

Tags: floating-point, binary

In simple precision format, the largest possible positive number is

$A = 0 ~~~ 11111110 ~~~ 111\ldots 111$

Its predecessor is

$B = 0 ~~~ 11111110 ~~~ 111 \ldots 110$

But what is the absolute difference (in decimal) between these?

Appealing to scientific notation,

$A = 0.(2^{22}+2^{23}+\ldots + 2 + 1) \times 2^{2^{7}+2^{6} + 2 + 1 - 127}$

and

$B = 0.(2^{22}+2^{23}+\ldots + 2 + 0) \times 2^{2^{7}+2^{6} + 2 + 1 - 127}$

So they have only a difference of one point in the last decimal digit. The exponent tells us there are $2^{7} + \ldots + 2 + 1 - 127$ such decimal points. Let $e$ denote that quantity. Is it correct to say the difference is

$$0.\overbrace{000\ldots 000}^{e \text{ times}}1$$

or am I missing something?

Comment: In the example, what is the numerical value of $e$? I am having trouble following the reasoning here, and it seems to me that the *implicit* leading bit (the integer bit) of the significand has been omitted. In IEEE-754 binary arithmetic, other than for subnormals, all significands are of the form $1.x \ldots x$, with $x \in {0, 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE-754 `binary32` format comprises a sign bit, eight exponent bits, and twenty-three *stored* significand bits. The stored exponent is biased by 127. For *normal* operands, the significand actually comprises twenty-four bits that encode values in $[1, 2)$. Since this means that the most significant bit of the significand is always 1, it is not stored. If we denote the largest finite `binary32` operand by $a$ and its immediate predecessor by $b$, their binary encodings are

```
       s exponent significand
   a = 0_11111110_11111111111111111111111  largest finite binary32
   b = 0_11111110_11111111111111111111110  its immediate predecessor
```

The most significant bit of the *stored* significand has numerical weight $2^{-1}$, while the least significant bit of the *stored* significand has numerical weight $2^{-23}$. If we take into account exponent bias, the numerical values of the two operands are

```
                   2⁰ 2⁻¹                   2⁻²³
                    ↓ ↓                     ↓ 
   a = 2⁽²⁵⁴⁻¹²⁷⁾ * 1.11111111111111111111111
   b = 2⁽²⁵⁴⁻¹²⁷⁾ * 1.11111111111111111111110
```

The difference $a- b$ is therefore $2^{(254-127)} \cdot 2^{-23} = 2^{104} \approx 2.02824096 \cdot 10^{31}$. We could also confirm this experimentally, for example with the following ISO-C99 program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t ai = 0x7f7fffff; // largest finite binary32
    uint32_t bi = 0x7f7ffffe; // its immediate predecessor
    float a, b, diff;
    memcpy (&a, &ai, sizeof a);
    memcpy (&b, &bi, sizeof b);
    diff = a - b;
    printf ("diff = %15.8e  %15.6a  log2(diff)=%f\n", diff, diff, log2f (diff));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```